Error bounds for ill-conditioned linear systems
I have two ill-conditioned linear systems,
$$
P_X = P_Yq \\
\hat{P}_X = \hat{P}_Y \hat{q},
$$
where the left-hand sides are column vectors, $P_Y$ and $\hat{P}_Y$ are non-square matrices and where I know that there are infinite solution vectors $q$ and $\hat{q}$ for each of the systems. The first system is the "true" one and the second is the same system but measured with error.
Denote by $A$ and $B$ the set of solutions of the first and second system respectively.
I know by Daniel (1973) that if $q_1 \in B$, then there exists a $q_0 \in A$ such that
$$
||q_0 - q_1||_{\infty} \leq c(P_Y) || (P_Y - \hat{P}_Y) q_1 - (P_X - \hat{P}_X)||_{\infty}, 
$$
where $c(P_Y)$ is a constant that depends on $P_Y$. This previous bound is Hoffman's Theorem (Hoffman (1952)) but without the inequality part. My first question: is this statement true? Meaning that I can take out the inequality and this upper bound still holds.
Going to the second question, if the previous statement is true, how do I find a bound for the constant? I have read some literature about this, but it usually relies on the fact that $P_Y$ is invertible to be able to use its condition number, which is not my case. Some other articles focus on the polyhedron of the solutions produced by an inequality of the type $Dz \leq d$, which is not the case either.
If anybody has some insights, references or ideas I would be more than glad.
References:
Daniel (1973)
Hoffman (1952)

I believe you are missing a $q_0$ term inside the right-hand side of your inequality (i.e. $(P_X - \hat P_X)$ should be $(P_X - \hat P_X)q_0$).

Hello @mhdadk I do not think so. Please see the first page of Daniel (1973).

Nevermind, I was confused by your notation. $P_X$ and $\hat P_X$ are vectors here, not matrices, while $P_Y$ and $\hat P_Y$ are matrices.

@mhdadk ah, I will make my notation a bit clearer. Thanks.
